# Css transition does not work

Tags: html, css

I couldn't get transitions to that div , i do not know why ,
i tried many times without any success

```css
.desc-mov {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: black;
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  line-height: 1.5;
  transition: 5s;

  position: absolute;
}

.desc-mov:hover {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="desc-mov ">
    <p > how are you are that working</p>               

               </div>
```

Comment: you need to set an initial value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a default value for an absolute position in order to make it work.
Try this:

```css
.desc-mov {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: black;
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  line-height: 1.5;
  transition: 5s;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.desc-mov:hover {
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="desc-mov ">
    <p > how are you are that working</p>               
</div>
```